# PyPI Request Entity Too Large (Download Data as first step)

Tags: python, pypi

Hi all I'm developing a script that will need to use about 150Mb of compressed data (tar.gz) that is not publicly available.

I tried to host the script on PyPI but get this error

```
Upload failed (413): Request Entity Too Large
error: Upload failed (413): Request Entity Too Large
```

So I would like to circumvent this by hosting the tarball of data on dropbox and downloading and decompressing as a first step. I'm new to PyPI so I'll explain what I would like to do in pseudo-code

```
# user runs pip install "myscript"
# before installing script wget tarball
cd myscript/
wget www.dropbox/data.tar.gz 
tar zxvf data.tar.gz
# now data is in myscript/data

#continue with setup.py with package_data in myscript/data
```

I already ensured the package data will not be installed in /usr but only in myscript/

I've also coded myscript to use the `__file__` variable with proper exception handling

**TL;DR** I have non-public data that I can host on dropbox indefinitely. I would like to have a PyPI script that downloads, decompresses the data in the proper directory. Then runs the setup.py

**How do I wget and decompress a tarball with all my package_data as a part of setup.py** 
Thanks!

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How do I wget and decompress a tarball with all my package data as in setup.py